# how to optimize XML writing method?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, performance, optimization

I can only use the .NET 2.0 framework to create an XML document (> 1000 lines).

The information for the document is retrieved from the Windows Registry. The XML is written using 2 for loops and in these loops I call 3 the .ToString() method to convert the retrieved data.

As expected, it takes ages to create the XML document. I was wondering what can I do to optimize this.

```
public static void InitiateApp()
{
    const string regadd = "SOFTWARE" + "\\" +  "\\" + "Microsoft" + "\\" + "Windows NT" + "\\" +  "CurrentVersion" + "\\Fonts";
    RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regadd);
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.CloseOutput = true;
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";
    settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("c:\\out.xml",settings);
    foreach (FontFamily font in FontFamily.Families)
    {
        w.WriteStartElement("FontFamily");
        int keyCount = 0;
        foreach (string key in regkey.GetValueNames())
        {   
            if(regkey.GetValueNames()[keyCount].ToString().Contains(font.Name)) 
            {
                         w.WriteStartElement("FontName",regkey.GetValueNames()[keyCount].ToString());
                         w.WriteElementString("FontFile",regkey.GetValue(key).ToString());
             w.WriteEndElement();
            }
            keyCount++;
        }
        w.WriteEndElement();
    }
    w.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a stopwatch and outputting how long each of your calls are taking?  It could help you isolate what's taking so long.

Comment: It's a single call when application initiates, so that I can store these information to an XML for later use. As it's quite heavy to search through registry every time. So I decided to put everything inside the xml and query from it.

Comment: @rie819, No i havent tried that, could explain more? thanks

Comment: What is `regkey`? The `start`/`end` writes are not matching for `newElement`. Can you post compilable code please?

Comment: @Kourosh the stopwatch is used to measure how long something takes:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the registry access from the xml writing.  Then you can measure each and see which is slow.

---

```
regkey.GetValueNames()[keyCount].ToString()
```

GetValueNames returns a string[], why call ToString?

```
foreach (string key in regkey.GetValueNames()) 
//...
if(regkey.GetValueNames()[keyCount].ToString().Contains(font.Name)) 
//...
w.WriteStartElement("FontName",regkey.GetValueNames()[keyCount].ToString());
```

Why call GetValueNames so much?

Answer (score 2):

Move the multiple calls to `GetValueNames` out of the loop and intialize a string array instead.  That will make at least some small improvement.

```
string[] vals = regkey.GetValueNames();
XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("c:\\out.xml",settings); 
foreach (Xtype a in all_a) 
{
    w.WriteStartElement("newElement");     
    int keyCount = 0;     
    foreach (YType b in all_b)     
    {            
         if(vals[keyCount].ToString().Contains(a.name))          
         {
             w.WriteStartElement("a_name",vals[keyCount].ToString());                  
             w.WriteElementString("b_name",regkey.GetValue(key).ToString());             
             w.WriteEndElement();
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use linq to xml to write the document. Personally I feel like its a more straight forward method.

Comment: unfortunately it's not available in .net 2 :(

Comment: Use LinqBridge (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) and Visual Studio's multi-targetting feature if you want to use LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the retrieval of the data from the registry is taking longer than your serialization. 
What you could do is use a producer consumer pattern to multithread the retrieval of keys from the registry (not sure that would help)... and then use a single consumer to write them out.

See [Blocking Collection and the Producer-Consumer Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx)